# Match suffixes s and ed in regex - javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, highlighting

I am using this regex to match words in an html page.

```
\b(wordtosearch)\b(?!')
```

The forward negative lookhead is to prevent matching words having ' like **don** in **don't**

however i also want to match words that may or may not have **s** or **ed** at the end.

like if i have to search for **test** then it should match **tests** or **tested**.

Also please note that **wordtosearch** can contain many words seperated with | sign i.e car|truck

i realize that it would require a positive lookahead but i dont know how to make all this work.

Comment: `(wordtosearch)(s|ed)?`

Comment: `/\b(test)(s|ed)?\b(?!')/.test('tested')`

Comment: thanks...that works..please post it as an answer so that i can mark it as the accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(wordtosearch)(s|ed)?` would do the trick. It will check that the search word is followed by optional `s` or `ed` suffix.

Example:

```
/\b(test)(s|ed)?\b(?!')/.test('tested')
```

Comment: is there a way to match tested but in the result get only test since there is post match logic that searches some data based on the word from a lookup table and while the data exists for TEST it will not exist for TESTED?

Comment: @Pankaj Kumar: `'tested'.match(/\b(test)(?:s|ed)?\b(?!')/)`

Answer (score 1):

You could generalize the whole search to:

```
(?=.*\w)((?:\w|')+)
```

That will match any word even if it includes an apostrophe.